# MS Chatbot is not open chat conversation window in emulator on VM , getting 403 error with port 55415

Tags: botframework, bot-emulator

Chatbot is not open chat conversation window in emulator 4.11. It is working in local machine but same thing is not working from client network VM, getting below error. Ngrok is working on same vm also having admin right.  Bot configuration is also fine.

[image]

Comment: Hi @tonyanziano , could you please check this issue  ? Bot emulator is not working in secure environment .

Comment: Have you raised this issue on the emulator repo?

Comment: not yet, could you please provide me exact contact details if you have?

Comment: Now, I have raised it on repo as well.

Comment: Below is the repo url.    https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/2241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved. VM outbound rules were blocking traffic and not able to connect bot authentication. Hence it is working fine.

Thanks
Upendra